# Center Navbar On Blogger

Tags: html, css, navbar, blogger, centering

I want to center my navbar. I use Blogger's 'Simple Template'.

Code I found relevant:

```
.tabs-inner .widget ul {
        margin: 0 auto;
        background: transparent none repeat scroll bottom;
        border-radius: 0;
        width: 95%;
    }
```

Comment: Please add a JSFiddle with working HTML so we can see what is going on. CSS only is not enough.

Comment: you surely have many errors in yor reported CSS, missing selectors and parentesis. Please, fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your template, a combination of the following *should* work (try applying them all, and if desired result occurs, gradually remove till you see the result reverse to original. The last removed will be necessary):

```
#blog-pager {
  margin: 0px;
}
```

.

```
.widget {
  margin: 0px;
}
```

.

```
.main-inner .column-center-inner .section {
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right:0px;
}
```

.

```
.tabs-inner .widget ul {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

.

```
.tabs-inner, .section {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the value of :
Exemple :

```
#navbar-iframe 
{
  background: transparent !important;  
}

.site-header h1, 
.site-header h2 
{
  text-align: center;
}

.header-inner .Header .titlewrapper, 
.header-inner .Header .descriptionwrapper 
{
  padding-left: 50;
  padding-right: 50;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Let me know